# how to represent following string using regular expression?

Tags: regex, msbuildcommunitytasks

I want to represent following string using regular expression.

This is the sentence:

```
pro displ = "monitor" id="1"
```

I tried this:

```
pro displ=(("[^"]*")monitor(("[^"]*") id =(("[^"]*")1(("[^"]*")
```

but it is not working.as i was new to regular expression please help me to solve this issue

Comment: What is the string you want to anlyze, what is the value you want to get and what is your regex?

Comment: my string is <prop disp ="monitor " id="1">.i want regex of this one

Comment: And what value to want to get out of the string? Or do you just want to check the whole string?

Comment: yes i want to check the whole string

Comment: @Nithin: You're trying to [match XML with REs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)?

Comment: @Donal Fellows .yes i am trying to match xml node with res

Answer (score 0):

```
<prop.*disp=\"(.*)\".*id=\"(.*)\".*>
```

You can use this one, and then match the parentheses to change what you want.

Instead this one with the 'sed' utility:

```
<prop.*disp=\"\(.*\)\".*id=\"\(.*\)\".*>
```

Comment: actually i want to check xml node starting <prop disp ="monitor " id="1"> </pro>.so i want regular expression equivalent to this to so that i can replace this with another one such as <prop disp = "xyz".i am using msbuild where iam using fileupdate to do the operation

Comment: Try with this new one, I succesfully used it with JS.

Comment: Regex="&lt;Prop Display =\"\ Monitor\" id=\"\1\" &gt;(.*?)&lt;/Prop&gt;".i tried like this but it is not working .the problem is due t the double quotes.how to represent double quotes using regular expression

Comment: Where are you using this expression? The syntax has little differences depending on the program/API you use.. Usually double quotes are represented by escaping them, such as: \"

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work to match the string:

```
pro\sdispl=["]monitor["]\sid=["]1["]
```

Comment: i tried  like this (("[^"]*")for doubles quotes but it is showing some error in msbuild.i think that error  is due to the [ square bracket.